# Can you directly specify the synced_property_name when creating a relation through the Notion API?

Tags: notion-api

When [creating a database](https://developers.notion.com/reference/create-a-database) (see example), [you can specify](https://developers.notion.com/reference/property-schema-object) the directionality of the relation through the `single_property` or `dual_property` properties. When using `dual_property`, the resulting field name on the opposite side is auto-generated following this template: "Related to <this_database> (<this_field>)".

Is it possible to pre-specify a custom field name, as opposed to auto-generating and then renaming it (requires 2 API calls and some flow management)?